# React Native firebase [firestore/permission-denied]

Tags: firebase, react-native

Не буду долго ходить вокруг до около:
Проблема с firestore и auth. Ошибка с разрешениями

> Error: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.
> NativeFirebaseError: [firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.

Правила прописаны в FireStore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {


match/databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Users/{document=**} {
      allow read, get: if true;
      allow create, update: if request.auth.uid == resource.id;
  }
}
```

Используются следующие библиотеки

- @react-native-firebase/app
- @react-native-firebase/app-check
- @react-native-firebase/auth
- @react-native-firebase/firestore

И сам код:

```js
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
    
async function onAuthChanged(onChange) {
  auth().onAuthStateChanged(onChange);
}

async function authenticateUser(status) {
  // Получаем значение вошел в систему или вышел пользователь из системы.
  // Не из окна D
  if (status) {
    // Пользователь вошел в систему / пользователь уже был в системе
    const uid = status.uid;
    // По uid ищем пользователя в firestore и меняем состояние компонента
    
    let user = await firestore().collection('Users').doc(uid).get(); // Ошибка происходит на данной строке
    
    
    // Если документ с uid пользователя не будет найден в firestore, то он автоматически создаться
    return ({
      user: {...user.data(), uid} ?? {login: undefined, birthday: undefined, uid}
    });
  } else {
    // Пользователь вышел из системы / пользователя не было в системе
    return { user: null };
  }
}

onAuthChanged(async (status) => {
  const { user } = await authenticateUser(status);
});
```

P.S. В fireStore: правила работают [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ayd5.png)

P.S.S Вариант, которые говорят просто поставить

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
   allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```

это не помогает все равно

Answer (score 0):

Была включена проверка приложения в FireStore, а в приложение не был настроен AppCheck